# TSQL optimization of sproc with multiple similar subqueries

Tags: t-sql, optimization

So, I have inherited someones product, and while I am looking at a lot of the code, I feel much of it can be improved.  My fist task, that I hope someone can put me on the right tracks with is optimizing the following stored proc.  Although I am quite green, I can't help feel that there must be a better way to do this... it takes 4+ minutes to run.

In the sproc, there are multiple times the same joins are made.  I really am not asking for someone to do my job, but please could someone give me a start as to how to better structure the following?:

Should I create a temp tables instead of doing so many nested joins?

Thanks,

```
BEGIN

DECLARE  @District VARCHAR(50)
SET @District =  '42'

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @today varchar(30) 
    DECLARE @ToDatestr varchar(20) 
    DECLARE @ToDate15 varchar(20) 
    DECLARE @BOYear varchar(30) 
    DECLARE @BOMonth varchar(30) 
    DECLARE @BOWeek varchar(30) 
    SET @today = RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(getdate()) as varchar), 2) + '/' + RIGHT('00'+CAST(DAY(getdate()) as varchar), 2) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(getdate()) as varchar) 
    SELECT  d.utilitydistrictnumber AS "District #",
            emr.ExistingMeterID,
            emr.isvc AS "ISVC #",
            r.Utilityrouteid AS "Utility Route #",
            emr.cyclenumber AS "Utility Cycle #",
            pd."Name",
            REPLACE(REPLACE(pd."Address",CHAR(10),''),',',';') AS 'Address',
            CONVERT(float,(CASE WHEN ISNULL(p.Latitude,'.000000') = '.000000' THEN dw_p.Lat ELSE p.Latitude END)) AS 'Latitude',
            CONVERT(float,(CASE WHEN ISNULL(p.Longitude,'.000000') = '.000000' THEN dw_p.Long ELSE p.Longitude END)) AS 'Longitude',
            WeekendCustContact.mCount AS 'Weekend CustContact',
            After5PMCustContact.mCount AS 'After 5PM CustContact',
            TotalCustContact.mCount AS 'Total CustContact',
            AppointmentArranged.mCount AS 'Appointment Arranged',
            FieldUTC.mCount AS 'Total FieldUTCs',
            Letters.TotalHTALetter ,
            emr.UtilityOnHold,
            emr.DeploymentOnHold,
            emr.DeploymentOnHoldReason,
            ,o.ActivityName
        From  Product_CompanyProd_Repository.dbo.Existingmetersroutes emr (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
        Product_CompanyProd_Repository.dbo.ExistingmetersPremises emp (NOLOCK)
                ON emp.existingmeterid = emr.existingmeterid
        INNER JOIN
        Product_CompanyProd_Repository.dbo.Premises p (NOLOCK)
                ON p.premiseid = emp.premiseid
        LEFT JOIN
        [ProductMAIN-ALIAS].[DW_Company].[dbo].[Premise_LatLongs] dw_p (NOLOCK)
                ON dw_p.premiseid = p.premiseid
        INNER JOIN
        [Product_CompanyPROD_Repository].[dbo].[routes] AS r     (NOLOCK)
            ON r.routeid = emr.routeid
        INNER JOIN 
        [Product_CompanyPROD_Repository].[dbo].[Districts] AS d  (NOLOCK)
            ON d.districtid = r.districtid AND d.utilitydistrictnumber = @District
        LEFT JOIN [Product_CompanyProd].[dbo].[ODMorders] o
            ON o.summary = emr.isvc AND o.StatusID < 9
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT oo.Summary AS ISVC, COUNT(*) AS mcount
                    FROM Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders AS oo  (NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN
                        Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrderAttributesUME AS oa  (NOLOCK)
                                ON oa.Orderid = oo.Orderid  AND oa.UTCCode <> '' 
                                    AND oa.district = @District 
                    WHERE oo.StatusID IN (9,10) 
                    GROUP BY oo.summary 
            ) AS FieldUTC ON FieldUTC.isvc=emr.isvc
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT e.isvc, COUNT(*) AS mcount
                FROM [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmetersroutes] e  (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN
                [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmeterspremises] p  (NOLOCK)
                    on e.existingmeterid = p.existingmeterid
                INNER JOIN 
                [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[premisenotes] pn  (NOLOCK)
                    on pn.premiseid = p.premiseid
                        AND DATEPART(dw, pn.autotimestamp) IN (7,1)
                WHERE category = 'Call attempt'
                GROUP BY e.isvc

            ) AS WeekendCustContact ON WeekendCustContact.isvc=emr.isvc
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT e.isvc, COUNT(*) AS mcount
                FROM [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmetersroutes] e  (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN
                [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmeterspremises] p  (NOLOCK)
                    on e.existingmeterid = p.existingmeterid
                INNER JOIN 
                [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[premisenotes] pn  (NOLOCK)
                    on pn.premiseid = p.premiseid
                        AND datepart(hh,pn.autotimestamp) >= 17
                WHERE category = 'Call attempt'
                GROUP BY e.isvc

            ) AS "After5PMCustContact" ON After5PMCustContact.isvc=emr.isvc
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT e.isvc, COUNT(*) AS mcount
                FROM [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmetersroutes] e (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN
                [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmeterspremises] p  (NOLOCK)
                    on e.existingmeterid = p.existingmeterid
                INNER JOIN 
                [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[premisenotes] pn  (NOLOCK)
                    on pn.premiseid = p.premiseid
                WHERE category IN ('Call attempt','Door hanger','Letter received by customer','Call to Company who referred the caller to OurCompany')
                GROUP BY e.isvc

            ) AS "TotalCustContact" ON TotalCustContact.isvc=emr.isvc
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT oo.Summary AS ISVC, COUNT(*) AS mcount
                    FROM Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders AS oo (NOLOCK) 
                    WHERE oo.ActivityName = 'CompanyExchangeAppt' AND oo.StatusID < 9 
                    GROUP BY oo.summary
            ) AS "AppointmentArranged" ON AppointmentArranged.isvc=emr.isvc
        LEFT JOIN

            (SELECT emr.ISVC,ema.ColumnValue AS "TotalHTALetter"
            FROM 
                Product_CompanyProd_Repository.dbo.Existingmetersroutes emr  (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN
                Product_CompanyProd_Repository.dbo.ExistingmetersAuxiliary ema   (NOLOCK) on ema.existingmeterid = emr.existingmeterid 
                    AND ema.ColumnName LIKE 'HTALetter%'
            ) AS "Letters" ON Letters.isvc=emr.isvc

        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM
        ( SELECT o.summary AS isvc,
            REPLACE(REPLACE([od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/PremiseDetails/Name)').value('.','varchar(50)'),CHAR(10),''),',',';') AS "Name",
            REPLACE(REPLACE([od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/Location/StreetAddress)').value('.','varchar(50)'),CHAR(10),''),',',';') AS "Address",
            [od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/PremiseDetails/Phone)').value('.','varchar(50)') AS "Phone",
            o.Autotimestamp
            From Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders AS o  (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN 
                Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrderAttributesUME AS oa  (NOLOCK)
                    ON oa.Orderid = o.Orderid  AND oa.district = @District AND oa.UTCCode <> ''
                INNER JOIN 
                [Product_CompanyProd].[dbo].[ODMOrderdetails] od  (NOLOCK)
                    ON od.Orderid = o.Orderid  
                WHERE o.StatusID IN (9,10)
        ) AS pd 
        WHERE  
                pd.Autotimestamp=(SELECT MAX(o.autotimestamp)
                                    From Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders AS o (NOLOCK)
                                        INNER JOIN 
                                        Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrderAttributesUME AS oa  (NOLOCK)
                                            ON oa.Orderid = o.Orderid  AND oa.district = @District 
                                        INNER JOIN 
                                        [Product_CompanyProd].[dbo].[ODMOrderdetails] od  (NOLOCK)
                                            ON od.Orderid = o.Orderid  
                                    WHERE o.summary = pd.isvc AND
                                            o.StatusID IN (9,10)
                                    )
        ) AS pd ON pd.isvc = emr.isvc 

        Where 
             emr.Status NOT IN ('Complete','Fieldcomplete','UTC') 

END
```

Comment: Difficult without knowing the primary keys, what indices are in place, the number of rows in these table (order of magnitude), and not knowing the business purpose of some of the columns.

Comment: Do you care for absolute accuracy?  NOLOCK allows dirty reads i.e. reading data that has not yet been commited.

Comment: Yeah thanks datagod.  We needed to put the no locks in due to times where there were heavy updates to the database and other users trying to run quite long reports.  Users were getting time outs.  In most cases though, the data for reports is not what the inserts are of.  It is usually the previous weeks data.  The nolocks are not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

These 3 subqueries could be combined:

```
...
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT e.isvc, COUNT(*) AS mcount
        FROM [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmetersroutes] e  (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmeterspremises] p  (NOLOCK)
            on e.existingmeterid = p.existingmeterid
        INNER JOIN 
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[premisenotes] pn  (NOLOCK)
            on pn.premiseid = p.premiseid
                AND DATEPART(dw, pn.autotimestamp) IN (7,1)
        WHERE category = 'Call attempt'
        GROUP BY e.isvc

    ) AS WeekendCustContact ON WeekendCustContact.isvc=emr.isvc
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT e.isvc, COUNT(*) AS mcount
        FROM [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmetersroutes] e  (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmeterspremises] p  (NOLOCK)
            on e.existingmeterid = p.existingmeterid
        INNER JOIN 
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[premisenotes] pn  (NOLOCK)
            on pn.premiseid = p.premiseid
                AND datepart(hh,pn.autotimestamp) >= 17
        WHERE category = 'Call attempt'
        GROUP BY e.isvc

    ) AS "After5PMCustContact" ON After5PMCustContact.isvc=emr.isvc
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT e.isvc, COUNT(*) AS mcount
        FROM [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmetersroutes] e (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmeterspremises] p  (NOLOCK)
            on e.existingmeterid = p.existingmeterid
        INNER JOIN 
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[premisenotes] pn  (NOLOCK)
            on pn.premiseid = p.premiseid
        WHERE category IN ('Call attempt','Door hanger','Letter received by customer','Call to Company who referred the caller to OurCompany')
        GROUP BY e.isvc

    ) AS "TotalCustContact" ON TotalCustContact.isvc=emr.isvc
...
```

Here's a possible combined version:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        e.isvc,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, pn.autotimestamp) IN (7, 1) AND category = 'Call attempt' THEN 1 END) AS WeekendCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hh, pn.autotimestamp) >= 17     AND category = 'Call attempt' THEN 1 END) AS After5PMCount
    FROM [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmetersroutes] e (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[existingmeterspremises] p  (NOLOCK)
            on e.existingmeterid = p.existingmeterid
        INNER JOIN 
        [Product_CompanyProd_Repository].[dbo].[premisenotes] pn  (NOLOCK)
            on pn.premiseid = p.premiseid
        WHERE category IN ('Call attempt','Door hanger','Letter received by customer','Call to Company who referred the caller to OurCompany')
        GROUP BY e.isvc

    ) AS "CustContact" ON CustContact.isvc=emr.isvc
```

Of course, you'll also need to replace the corresponding columns in the select list.

Another possible cause of the query's slow performance is this little monster:

```
...
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM
( SELECT o.summary AS isvc,
    REPLACE(REPLACE([od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/PremiseDetails/Name)').value('.','varchar(50)'),CHAR(10),''),',',';') AS "Name",
    REPLACE(REPLACE([od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/Location/StreetAddress)').value('.','varchar(50)'),CHAR(10),''),',',';') AS "Address",
    [od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/PremiseDetails/Phone)').value('.','varchar(50)') AS "Phone",
    o.Autotimestamp
    From Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders AS o  (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN 
        Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrderAttributesUME AS oa  (NOLOCK)
            ON oa.Orderid = o.Orderid  AND oa.district = @District AND oa.UTCCode <> ''
        INNER JOIN 
        [Product_CompanyProd].[dbo].[ODMOrderdetails] od  (NOLOCK)
            ON od.Orderid = o.Orderid  
        WHERE o.StatusID IN (9,10)
) AS pd 
WHERE  
      pd.Autotimestamp=(SELECT MAX(o.autotimestamp)
                            From Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders AS o (NOLOCK)
                                INNER JOIN 
                                Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrderAttributesUME AS oa  (NOLOCK)
                                    ON oa.Orderid = o.Orderid  AND oa.district = @District 
                                INNER JOIN 
                                [Product_CompanyProd].[dbo].[ODMOrderdetails] od  (NOLOCK)
                                    ON od.Orderid = o.Orderid  
                            WHERE o.summary = pd.isvc AND
                                    o.StatusID IN (9,10)
                          )
) AS pd ON pd.isvc = emr.isvc 
...
```

And here's how I would rewrite it:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        o.summary AS isvc,
        REPLACE(REPLACE([od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/PremiseDetails/Name)').value('.','varchar(50)'),CHAR(10),''),',',';') AS "Name",
        REPLACE(REPLACE([od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/Location/StreetAddress)').value('.','varchar(50)'),CHAR(10),''),',',';') AS "Address",
        [od].Information.query('data(OrderDetails/PremiseDetails/Phone)').value('.','varchar(50)') AS "Phone",
        o.Autotimestamp
    From Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders AS o  (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN 
        Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrderAttributesUME AS oa  (NOLOCK)
            ON oa.Orderid = o.Orderid  AND oa.district = @District AND oa.UTCCode <> ''
        INNER JOIN 
        [Product_CompanyProd].[dbo].[ODMOrderdetails] od  (NOLOCK)
            ON od.Orderid = o.Orderid  
    WHERE o.StatusID IN (9,10)
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrders o2
          INNER JOIN Product_CompanyProd.dbo.ODMOrderAttributesUME AS oa2  (NOLOCK)
            ON oa2.Orderid = o2.Orderid  AND oa2.district = @District AND oa2.UTCCode <> ''
        WHERE o.summary = o2.summary AND o2.StatusID IN (9,10) AND o.Autotimestamp < o2.Autotimestamp
      )
    ) AS pd ON pd.isvc = emr.isvc
```

Comment: Andriy, that is a great start for me.  Thanks so much.

I will make the amendments and let you know how the performance looks.

Comment: @Kipper007: You are welcome. I noticed a mistake in my second query. Had to make it a bit more complex as a result. Still, I think it should work faster than the original.

Comment: @Andriy: hey again, just wonder if you you could explain something in the 'monster' query for me please?

I get most of your restructure, but what I don't understand is the 'NOT EXISTS' clause.  Could you tell me what it refers to? I understand 
    ival not exists in (1,2,3,4)
but the AND NOT EXISTS does not refer to a particular column?

Sorry for being so confused!!

Comment: @Kipper007: Basically, IN and NOT IN have this form: `value [NOT] IN (list)`. `List` could be an explicit list of values or a subselect that returns *just one column* (which provides us with a list of values). The IN/NOT IN predicate returns `true` when the given value is found/not found in the list. Now, EXISTS and NOT EXTSTS use this form: `[NOT] EXISTS (subselect)`. Note the absence of a `value` of any sort to the left of the predicate. The result is `true` if the subselect returns *any* rows. (That's why it's `SELECT *...`: you don't care about *columns*, but you do about *rows*.) ...

Comment: (cont.) In my first replacement for that large subquery I used the *LEFT JOIN to self* approach to find the maximum value of `Autotimestamp`. Basically the approach is like this: `SELECT a.* FROM a LEFT JOIN a AS a2 ON a.key = a2.key AND a.value < a2.value WHERE a2.key IS NULL`. This returns all the rows from `a` with the largest `value`s. I then decided to use an equivalent NOT EXISTS form instead: `SELECT * FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM a AS a2 WHERE a.key = a2.key AND a.value < a2.value)`. That's because `a AS a2` in my (your) case had to be a join of tables, not just one table.

Comment: @Andriy, Thanks again man.  I am getting there... just need to read through it a couple more times :-)

Answer (score 1):

yes, looking at that, it can be optimized. Right off the bat, you can change the line

```
SET @today = RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(getdate()) as varchar), 2) + '/' +
             RIGHT('00'+CAST(DAY(getdate()) as varchar), 2) + '/' +
             CAST(YEAR(getdate()) as varchar)
```

to

```
SET @today = convert(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
```

which leads me to believe there are other things you can do to help out the performance. Looking at it makes me think they were trying to build a pivot table or matrix report, try rebuilding the query in test using the PIVOT command or a CTE(Common Table Expression). I would be inclined to try the CTE first.
--chris

These link to the SQL 2005 references on MSDN

[Pivot Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

[CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)